# IOS chat room app via node.js about sending image

Tags: ios, node.js, tcp

This is my first question on stackoverflow. absolutely, this issue evolve around me many days. I am programming a chat app using node.js as the server, Here the server code:

```
var net = require('net');
var chatServer = net.createServer(),clientList = [];

chatServer.on("connection", function(client){
        client.name = client.remoteAddress + ":" + client.remotePort;
        console.log(client.name);

        client.write("Hi!\n");
        clientList.push(client);
        client.on("data",function(data){
                console.log(data);
                broadcast(data,client);
                })

})

chatServer.listen(1234);

function broadcast(message,client){
        var cleanup = [];
        for(var i=0;i<clientList.length;i++){
        if(client != clientList[i]){
                if(clientList[i].writable){
                        clientList[i].write(client.name = message);
                } else {
                cleanup.push[clientList[i]];
                clientList[i].destroy();
                }
        }
        }
}
```

It's ok in sending text, but when send image, once the node.js default buffer is full(because  the image is big enough,so the buffer contain  part of the image), it's will execute below code

```
client.on("data",function(data){
                console.log(data);
                broadcast(data,client);
```

and the other client only receive part of the image data.
 My idea is create a new buffer like:

```
buffer += data;
```

but I don't known how to detect the image boundary so that I could send the new buffer data to  other client.
How can I solve this problem, please help... and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a question about nodejs or chat app, its a general question about protocol design.

You can use/design your protocol based on existed ones:

1. ProtocolBuffer, powered by Google: https://github.com/google/protobuf , and this is one of the ProtocolBuffer implementations in nodejs: https://github.com/mafintosh/protocol-buffers
2. RPC, one of the implementation in nodejs:
   http://www.zerorpc.io
3. Design your own and simple one: server side receives data in this order repeatedly:

type: int, length: int, body: bytes

which means the client side should follow this rule every time it is going to interact with server, send an "int" first to indicate the message type, then an "int" to indicate the length of the message, finally the message body.

If you are going to build highly scalable and large project, I recommend that you use ProtocolBuffer. Or you design a simple protocol(like what I wrote in 3) if you are writing a practice project.

Comment: thanks for rapidly and detail answer, but I just want to send image as send the text. look the code I gave above, when I send text message, it doesn't need any protocol design.The Server receive text message data from one client, and send it to another in one runloop. I want to send image as simple as the text message did.

Comment: @suoyong the problem you have for sending image is detecting the image boundary, which should be told by client side. the client should send the image data length before sending the image data, or the server side has no idea about where is the end of the image data.

Comment: @suoyong recommend you to learn more about how HTTP is designed, you will know how to design a protocol.